# MySQL - select records with specific match in one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in getting records in 1 to many relationship. following is the scenario,

```
table products
---------------------
id | name
---------------------
1 | product1
2 | product2
3 | product3
4 | product4


Categories
-------------
id | name
-------------
1 | A
2 | B
3 | C


product_categories
-------------------
pid | cid
-------------------
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 3
```

I want to select products based on category name.

if my condition is category B and C then the expected output would be,

Expected Result:

```
----------------------------
Product_name |  category_name
----------------------------
Product2 | B
Product2 | c
Product3 | B
Product3 | c
```

if my category is C then only product4 should be shown.

Please help me in this.. I have tried so many ways and techniques like IN, NOT IN, exists and not exists along with possible join operations but nothing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to count the number of instances of record which is equal to your supplied number of parameters in `IN` clause.

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    products a
        INNER JOIN product_categories b
            on a.id = b.pid
        INNER JOIN Categories c
            on b.cid = c.id
WHERE   c.name IN ('B','C')
GROUP BY a.NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: This would pull a record if it had only two B categories or only two C categories wouldn't it?

Comment: No, i have tried this way too. product1 will be included in the result because when mysql selects based on this condition, even product1 will have the count 2.

Comment: @SenthilRaj weird, I tried it on my server and it gives exactly what you typed in expected results

Comment: @xception: please ty this. add product5 and map it with categories A and C. now try your query, result will have product5.

Comment: @SenthilRaj thanks for the clarification, will remove my answer

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.pid
INNER JOIN Categories c ON pc.cid = c.id
WHERE c.name IN('B', 'C');
```

Comment: this would not give the desired results

Comment: because it will also return product ids 1 and 4

Comment: it returns 7 rows instead of the expected 4